# Scroll in custom editor while having focus in textbox (in a panel) @C#

Tags: c#, scroll

following situation:

Custom Editor Control (with scrollbars) and a search function in a panel (textbox in panel).
When having the focus on the textbox/panel it should be scrollable.

I already tried using override Scroll methodes but mostly the event isn't triggerd.
There isn't even an event for scrolling in WinForms textboxes so i have no idea on how to catch it.

Any ideas / WinAPI hooks? Thanks

Comment: Please show us your code. In any case, bear in mind that the scrollbars are made visible/invisible thanks to boolean properties (e.g., AutoScroll), not to methods.

Comment: There is no real code needed. I'm just looking for a way on how to scroll in a not focused element.

Comment: You cannot do anything in a "not focused" control. The whole point of having the focus is telling which control are you currently using.

Answer (score 0):

**How** do you want to scroll? By pressing **PgUp** and **PgDn**? Catch the keys and do the scrolling yourself. If not, please explain exactly what user interaction(s) should cause the scrolling!

```
private void yourSearchTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.PageDown) scrollPgDn();
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.PageUp) scrollPgUp();
    //..
}
```

Your scroll functions would either call custom editor methods or use some logic to do a reasonable scroll. You would set the focus on the editor before and set it back to your search textbox after the scrolling.

Comment: Okay.. I have a custom text editor and a panel that contains a search function. If i search the focus is the textbox/button/panel whatever. At this point you can't scroll in the text up or down as it does not have the focus. I don't wanna lose the focus but be able to scroll it (with the mouse wheel)

Comment: OK. For the Mousewheel events the same logic would apply. You just have to add the handler yourself like this:
 `code`           InitializeComponent();
            this.textBox1.MouseWheel += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.scrollPgDwn);`code`
and you would want to expand the signature of the scrol functions to include the events arguments like this
`code`private void scrollPgDwn(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)`code`. If you want to call them from the keydown event you could set the params to null.

Comment: And obviously, if you let the focus rest on the button after it is pressed, you will want to hook up with the same events of the button. Or you set the focus back to the search field at the end of the button's click event.